# Model are far away from center grid

Tags: 3d-view, bones, transforms

I'm a newbie in Blender, but I've noticed one of my friend's models is not placed exactly at the center of the grid.

I've grabbed the model and placed it in the center, but manipulator with root bone also moves, but I want to keep root bone in the center of the grid as well.

Here are some screenshots with my problem

[image: http://imgur.com/a/zhoxz]

Root bone placed correctly (by default) in the center of the grid, but the model is away from the center.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/WRsbF]

Ok, the model is in the spot that I want it to be, but root bone moved away from center grid?

BTW I'm using blender 2.77 version

Answer (score 2):

To place an object to the center and also change the pivot point to the object's center, follow these steps:

1. Select your object and tab into edit mode.
2. Hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select the whole mesh
3. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and select "Cursor to Selected"
4. Tab into Object Mode and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
5. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and select "Cursor to Center"
6. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> again and select "Selection to Cursor"

[image]

**If this answer solves your problem, please vote and also mark it as "accepted"**

Comment: @RichardLalancette - feel free to try. Also, please remember that **stackexchange is not your random average forum**, which means that comments are very much appreciated **as long as they add at least some value** to a question or and answer.

Comment: SHFT+CTRL+ALT+C no longer works as of v2.81.  Blender is awesome, but the ever changing behavior invalidades tutos pretty quick.

Answer (score 1):

The center of your object is away from mesh center, that why it happens...

To correct that select your object in *object mode* (make sure that no other object is selected), press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and select '*origin to geometry*' or '*center of mass*'.

[image: Center of object before begin corrected]
[image: Applying correction]
[image: The origin of the object moved]

Comment: SHFT+CTRL+ALT+C no longer works as of v2.81.  Blender is awesome, but the ever changing behavior invalidades tutos pretty quick.